# Hash Function for "Equal Arrays"

Tags: java, hash

I'm working on a Java program. In the program, there's a class which has an integer array in the field. The class has to meet one requirement as below:

For two instances of this class, if the two corresponding integer arrays contains at least one common element, then the two classes are "equal". Else, they are not equal.

It's not difficult to overwrite the "equals" method for this class to satisfy this requirement. However, I had trouble in coming up with a corresponding Hash Function to overwrite the hashCode method. Anyone has any idea on the hash function for this class? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [javadoc for `equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), it must be *transitive:

> for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.

Your proposed implementation for `equals()` would violate that with the following sample case:

- `x` contains `1`
- `y` contains `1` and `2`
- `z` contains `2`

so even though `x` would "equal" `y` and `y` would "equal" `z`, `x` and `z` would not be "equal" because don't share any values.

Thus your proposal is badly flawed, and you shouldn't implement it.

To answer your question, it can't be done because the `hashCode()` would not be determinable without the context of what you're comparing the instance to.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian  . I should have realized the "transitive" issue. I'll then define a new method to compare this class rather than overwriting equals() .